# Symfony2 components, class instances

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-components

Question is why

```
$config = array(__DIR__ . '/app/config');
$locator = new Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator($config);
$loader = new Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\YamlFileLoader($locator);
$routes_collection = $loader->load('routes.yml');
```

Here **$routes_collection** is an instance of **Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection**, and this code works fine.

And here

```
# config.yml
file_locator:
    class:    Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator
    arguments:  ['%app_root%/app/config']

route_collection:
    class:    Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\YamlFileLoader
    arguments: ["@file_locator"]
    calls:
              - [load, ['routes.yml']]

#app.php
$routes_collection = $container->get('route_collection')
```

**$routes_collection** is an instance of **Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\YamlFileLoader** and if i use it with **Symfony\Component\Routing\Matcher\UrlMatcher** am getting:

```
Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\Routing\Matcher\UrlMatcher::__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection, instance of Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\YamlFileLoader given.
```

---

**Update**

@Pazi ツ, but how to be if i want to use **route_collection** in **matcher**

```
matcher:
    class:    Symfony\Component\Routing\Matcher\UrlMatcher
    arguments:  ["@route_collection", "@context"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course your service is an instance of `YamlFileLoader` because you configured this in the `class` attribute. The return value of the methods `calls` doesn't influence the instance type. You have to call the method in php, if you want to get the return value.

```
# config.yml
file_locator:
    class:    Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator
    arguments:  ['%app_root%/app/config']

yaml_file_loader:
    class:    Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\YamlFileLoader
    arguments: ["@file_locator"]

#app.php
$routes_collection = $container->get('yaml_file_loader')->load('routes.yml');
```

Comment: Thank you for this, i am updated question a little bit, problem is what i am trying to use all this with "matcher" service, maybe you have idea how to solve this via config?

Comment: Do the configuration via php instead of yaml?

Comment: Hehe, came to the same conclusion, and finished migrating to php about 20 minutes ago :) Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to take route_collection via config you need to define route_collection yaml_file_loader as the factory service of route_collection:

```
# config.yml
file_locator:
  class:    Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator
  arguments:  ['%app_root%/app/config']

yaml_file_loader:
  class: Symfony\Copmonent\Routing\Loader\YamlFileLoader
  arguments: [ "@file_locator" ]

route_collection:
  class: Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection
  factory_service: yaml_file_loader
  factory_method: load
  arguments: [ 'routes.yml' ]
```

This way you can do

```
$routes_collection = $container->get('route_collection');
```